# How to query taxonomy for a post type then include another post type with no tax

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I include these post types on a single query?

```
  events -> all
  guides -> all
  page -> only topnews tax
```

This is the query I use to list posts from events and guides custom post type:

```
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => array('events', 'guides'),
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post_status' =>'publish',
  ); 
   $newlist = get_posts( $args );
```

Now, I want to add post type page with a tax_query of `topnews` on the `$args`. I already registered taxonomy called `property` for page post type, and `topnews` is one of its categories.

```
   'tax_query' => array(
      array (
     'taxonomy' => 'property',
     'field' => 'slug',
     'terms' => 'topnews',
     )
   ),
```

I want to include this on the query but the events and guides post types won't show any results. Only page with topnews tax is showing.
How do I include all of this on a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use

$query1 = WP_Query(); // query without taxonomy
$query2 = WP_Query(); // query with taxonomy

$q1_posts = $query1->posts;
$q2_posts = $query2->posts;

$merged_posts = array_merge($q1_posts,$q2_posts);
```